# Network Packet Out-of-Order/Duplicate ACKs

Tags: linux, linux-networking

I'm currently having a very large problem with network performance from a new DataCenter that we just moved into, and honestly I'm at a loss where to proceed; so I'm looking for some inspiration.

The DataCenter has a managed network to which I do not have access, but we are in charge of managing our hosts within it.

**General Information**

- We have eleven hosts (all Debian Squeeze) in the DataCenter environment (Dell R210s and R710s).
- Each host has two active interfaces, which are setup in a bond0 active/passive setup (eth0 and eth1).
- The networking stack on the hosts is largely as per the default Debian setup, we aren't running with attempted performance optimizations or similar.
- The problem is identical/replicable on any of the eleven hosts, however only applies to traffic that crosses the network boundary (i.e. it does not apply to traffic between the internal hosts themselves).
- The DataCenter support team has hooked a laptop up to the same switch that the rest of the hosts are on and is unable to recreate the issue; and thus have said that it must be a configuration issue with the internal hosts themselves, and is NOT a problem with the network.

**The Problem**

On outbound transfers, the transfer starts quickly with a large window size, but on the remote server packets are received out-of-order and this in turn causes duplicate ACKs to be sent out.  In short order the window size has shrunk massively (it stabilizes between 40,000 and 60,000 bytes) and the transfer has gone from megabytes per second down to ~200-300KB/sec.

On inbound transfers, everything is "fine" (where "fine" is defined as 2MB/sec sustained transfer rates).

So, an SCP transfer of a 20MB file OUT of the datacenter will start at ~2.2MB/sec but drop off to ~275KB/sec and will take 01m14s in total, while the SCP transfer of the same 20MB file INTO the datacenter will start at ~2.2MB/sec, remain stable between ~2.0-2.2MB/sec and finish in 00m09s.

**What I Have Tried**

- I've verified that there is no negotiation confusion between the hosts and the network hardware -- all links are seen as 1GbE full duplex by all parties.
- I've tried disabling window scaling.
- I've tried shrinking net.ipv4.tcp_rmem and net.ipv4.tcp_wmem from their debian defaults.
- I've tried disabling bond0 and just transferring the files over a plain-jane eth0 interface.
- I've tried transferring to multiple far-flung external end-points; all share the same problem (i.e. I am sure that the problem is on the DataCenter end, and not on the other end).
- I've run mtr checks of the routes to the multiple external end-points (all of which I can replicate the problem on) -- the routes are disparate (not at all similar after a few hops), and while some of them show some level of packet loss; the fact that the behaviour is so similar across all of the endpoints (which have dissimilar routes and dissimilar levels of packet loss) leads me to believe that the problem isn't the fault of anything more than three or four hops from the internal DC (as those are the common hops for each route -- and those hops don't show any significant levels of packet loss).

Below is a traffic analysis of inbound/outbound traffic (from the perspective of the host in the DC).  As you can see there are (very) regular duplicate ACKs that keep the transfer speed far below what it should be.  Also note that on an inbound transfer, the same problem does not occur.

```
tshark -r outbound-bond0.pcap -q -z io,stat,1,\
  "COUNT(tcp.analysis.retransmission) tcp.analysis.retransmission",\
  "COUNT(tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack)tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack",\
  "COUNT(tcp.analysis.lost_segment) tcp.analysis.lost_segment",\
  "COUNT(tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission) tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission"
===================================================================
IO Statistics
Interval: 1.000 secs
Column #0: COUNT(tcp.analysis.retransmission) tcp.analysis.retransmission
Column #1: COUNT(tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack)tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack
Column #2: COUNT(tcp.analysis.lost_segment) tcp.analysis.lost_segment
Column #3: COUNT(tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission) tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission
                |   Column #0    |   Column #1    |   Column #2    |   Column #3    
Time            |          COUNT |          COUNT |          COUNT |          COUNT 
000.000-001.000                 8               22                0                2 
001.000-002.000                 4               28                0                3 
002.000-003.000                 4               33                0                4 
003.000-004.000                 4               25                0                3 
004.000-005.000                 3               28                0                3 
005.000-006.000                 4               38                0                4 
006.000-007.000                 6               22                0                4 
007.000-008.000                 4               14                0                2 
008.000-009.000                 5               33                0                4 
009.000-010.000                 1               10                0                1 
010.000-011.000                 4               25                0                2 
011.000-012.000                 2               25                0                2 
012.000-013.000                 3               35                0                3 
013.000-014.000                 2               23                0                2 
014.000-015.000                 4               50                0                4 
015.000-016.000                 3               22                0                2 
016.000-017.000                 5               28                0                3 
017.000-018.000                 3               29                0                3 
018.000-019.000                 3               31                0                3 
019.000-020.000                 5               17                0                2 
020.000-021.000                 4               40                0                4 
021.000-022.000                 7               27                0                3 
022.000-023.000                 5               37                0                4 
023.000-024.000                10               17                0                1 
024.000-025.000                 3               10                0                1 
025.000-026.000                 4                9                0                2 
026.000-027.000                 3               10                0                1 
027.000-028.000                 4               47                0                4 
028.000-029.000                 5               35                0                4 
029.000-030.000                 3               14                0                2 
030.000-031.000                 9               24                0                3 
031.000-032.000                 4               20                0                3 
032.000-033.000                 6               37                0                5 
033.000-034.000                 3               19                0                3 
034.000-035.000                 3               17                0                1 
035.000-036.000                 3               42                0                3 
036.000-037.000                 6               49                0                5 
037.000-038.000                 1                7                0                1 
038.000-039.000                 9               59                0                6 
039.000-040.000                 3               23                0                3 
040.000-041.000                 1               12                0                1 
041.000-042.000                 4               39                0                2 
042.000-043.000                 6               15                0                0 
043.000-044.000                 2               25                0                2 
044.000-045.000                 3               41                0                3 
045.000-046.000                 1                8                0                1 
===================================================================

tshark -r inbound-bond0.pcap -q -z io,stat,1,\
  "COUNT(tcp.analysis.retransmission) tcp.analysis.retransmission",\
  "COUNT(tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack)tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack",\
  "COUNT(tcp.analysis.lost_segment) tcp.analysis.lost_segment",\
  "COUNT(tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission) tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission"
===================================================================
IO Statistics
Interval: 1.000 secs
Column #0: COUNT(tcp.analysis.retransmission) tcp.analysis.retransmission
Column #1: COUNT(tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack)tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack
Column #2: COUNT(tcp.analysis.lost_segment) tcp.analysis.lost_segment
Column #3: COUNT(tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission) tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission
                |   Column #0    |   Column #1    |   Column #2    |   Column #3    
Time            |          COUNT |          COUNT |          COUNT |          COUNT 
000.000-001.000                 0                0                0                0 
001.000-002.000                 0                0                0                0 
002.000-003.000                 0                0                0                0 
003.000-004.000                 0                0                0                0 
004.000-005.000                 0                0                0                0 
005.000-006.000                 0                0                0                0 
006.000-007.000                 0                0                0                0 
007.000-008.000                 1               26                1                0 
008.000-009.000                 1               70                0                1 
009.000-010.000                21              184                5                4 
010.000-011.000                 4               42                4                2 
011.000-012.000                 9               48                3                2 
012.000-013.000                 0                0                0                0 
013.000-014.000                 0                0                0                0 
014.000-015.000                 1               29                1                1 
===================================================================
```

Frankly, I'm at an utter loss.  Suggestions for what to try next are very welcome.

Comment: Try hooking up a Windows computer or another Linux computer to the network and perform the same transfer tests. If the results are the same then you can keep pushing on the DC operator. If the results are different (meaning the transfer tests perform as expected) then you can look more closely at the existing Linux hosts.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the network to do this.  I'm at a remote location.

Comment: How do you provision new hosts? Does the DC provision them for you? At any rate, can you provision a new host running either Windows or a different Linux flavor in order to run a transfer test?

Comment: Yes, the datacenter provisions them for us.  I _could_ ask them to provision a new host running windows to carry out the tests; but the lead time on host provisioning is rather long and I'd like to solve this a bit quicker than that -- and honestly, this has already occurred.  The DC support staff has been unable to replicate the transfer problems from a laptop that they hooked into the switch; albeit to a different endpoint.

Comment: I understand, but here's what I'd say: 1. Have them provision a new host while you're troubleshooting other areas. That way if you haven't found an answer by the time the new host is provisioned then you can run the transfer tests on the new host. 2. If they're not testing the same file transfer to the same endpoint then the test isn't the same. They need to duplicate ALL of the conditions of your test, otherwise you won't be able to trust their results. Continued...

Comment: ...  3. I'm not saying that you shouldn't trust what they're telling you but you need to take a "trust but confirm" approach. I wouldn't ever take as a given anything anyone else tells me about a problem unless they can show me impirical evidence to support their case.

Comment: did they take one of your affected hosts offline and test from that port? that would be a better test.

Comment: @longneck, yes I asked them to do the same test using one of the ports from the affected servers, and they did that test and reported no problem (again though, to a different endpoint).

Comment: @joeqwerty Yeah, you're right there.  I'll attempt to get them to run another test from their laptop to the same remote endpoint, and see if I can get them to do that -- if that replicates the problem, then great.  If not, then at that point I'll ask them to provision another host using Windows to test out some other options.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help... I'm sure you'll get some more traction here with additional answers (in addition to longneck's very good answer) that will keep moving you toward a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

if you're sure that the problem is caused by out-of-order packets, then i can easily think of one thing that would cause your packets to go out of order: a multi-link etherchannel somewhere between you and the edge of the DC configured for per-packet round-robin load balancing. ask your provider to look for that specifically.

Comment: On the receiving (remote) end, I see out-of-order packets first and then the duplicate acks are sent to the sending (DC) host -- so yes, I am pretty sure that the out-of-order packets come first.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to continue: I'll ask the DC -- supposing we find a multi-link etherchannel so configured; what is the fix?

Comment: if the packet are coming this frequently out of order, then that means one of the links or switches or paths is being overloaded, leading to the packets being excessively delayed. they need to address that problem. however, that also probably need to turn off round-robin load balancing (which is only appropriate if you know that your app can handle it, which a provider can't know since it's not their apps).

Comment: OK, sounds reasonable.  I'll ask the datacenter about whether there is a multi-link etherchannel configured anywhere along the path from our servers to the edge of the DC.

Comment: The datacenter reports that "We do not employ per-packet round robin load balancing anywhere in our network at all."

Comment: I would run MTR and see what sort of packet loss is occurring, and where. During transfer as well as not (to see if it is associated with the data flow)